# Why I am getting not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) in my request?

Tags: forms, sqlite, flask

I am new to flask. It seems that problem in my retrieve request. I want get rows from table filtered by select value which I extract from the post request.

Here is my shema:

```
CREATE TABLE poll (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  sex TEXT NOT NULL,
  city TEXT NOT NULL,   
  emotion TEXT NOT NULL,
  month TEXT NOT NULL,
  poll_time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    
);
```

db.py:

```
import sqlite3
import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext


def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

**init**.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from . import db
from . import routes


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    # BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskapp.sqlite'),
        UPLOAD_FOLDER=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'uploads')
    )

    app.register_blueprint(routes.bp)
    app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='index')

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

route.py:

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, g, redirect, render_template, request, url_for, flash, current_app
)
from flaskapp.db import get_db
from flaskapp.form import ChoiceForm

bp = Blueprint('routes', __name__)

@bp.route('/poll-process', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def process():
    form =  ChoiceForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sel1 = request.form.get('sel')
        print(sel1)
        req1 = get_db().execute(
            'SELECT * FROM poll WHERE sex = ?',
            (sel1,)   
        ).fetchall()
        print(req1) 
    return render_template('process.html', form=form)
```

form.py:

```
from wtforms import Form, SelectField, SelectMultipleField, RadioField, SubmitField, validators

sel_choice1 = [ 
    ('m', 'man'), 
    ('w', 'woman'),
]

class ChoiceForm(Form):
    sel_sex = SelectField(u'Criteria', choices=sel_choice1)
    radio = RadioField(choices=[('csv', 'csv'), ('html', 'html')])
    submit = SubmitField(label='apply')
```

form.html:

```
<form method="post">
  <!-- select -->
  <div class="form-group mt-4">  
    <h2>Choose criteria to sort</h2>
    <!-- sex -->
    <select class="custom-select" name="sel"> <!-- multiple -->       
      {% for field in form.sel_sex %}
        <option>{{ field }}</option>    
      {% endfor %}      
    </select>
      ...
    </div>
    <!-- submit -->
    {{form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")}}
</form>
```

```
* Serving Flask app "flaskapp" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 231-471-963
m
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2019 14:12:01] "POST /poll-process HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/valentyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/valentyn/Dev/simple_python_web_app/flaskapp/routes.py", line 81, in process
    (sel1,)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 67, in convert_timestamp
    datepart, timepart = val.split(b" ")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2019 14:12:02] "GET /poll-process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2019 14:12:02] "GET /poll-process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2019 14:12:02] "GET /poll-process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2019 14:12:03] "GET /poll-process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2019 14:12:03] "GET /poll-process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I can see in Web Developer Network that my form returns such form data:

```
sel m
submit  apply
```

SQL request `SELECT * FROM poll WHERE sex = 'm';` also works perfectly in sqlitebrowser with my table.

So everything works, unfortunately, only separately. I will be thanksful for any help!

Comment: Why not the type of `poll_time` column DATETIME?

Comment: Cause I have timestamp field in csv file which I convert and split into month and poll_time fields.